# How to avoid index (numbering) in latex?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am working on Latex and R and using following code.

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
infile<-read.table("test.txt",sep="\t")
Col3 <- unique(infile[,3]) 
LCol3 <- length(Col3)
for (i in 1:LCol3) {


print(paste("Column", Col3[i]))
print(infile[infile[,3]==Col3[i],-3])
}
@
```

I am getting following output.

```
1] "Column C"
V1 V2 V4
1 A B D
2 X T K
[1] "Column Z"
V1 V2 V4
3 Z U M
4 E V R
5 Z U M
[1] "Column P"
V1 V2 V4
6 E V R
```

I want to avoid numbering and columns names. I want my output as follows.

```
"Column C"
A B D
X T K

"Column Z"
Z U M
E V R
Z U M

"Column P"
E V R
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

In general, `print` is the wrong tool for what you are trying to do. You should probably be using `cat` instead. Since your example isn't reproducible, here is a very simple example illustrating a somewhat similar use:

```
d <- data.frame(V1 = LETTERS[1:5],V2 = letters[1:5], V3 = 1:5)

for (i in 1:5){
    cat("Row",i,"\n")
    cat(unlist(d[i,]),"\n\n")
}

Row 1 
A a 1 

Row 2 
B b 2 

Row 3 
C c 3 

Row 4 
D d 4 

Row 5 
E e 5
```

Note the need to unlist the data frame row, in order for `cat` to be able to sensibly paste the individual elements together.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to **stackoverflow** @Manish. 
As for removing the numbering use`latex`and `rowname=FALSE`. See below...
DATA

```
Age  <- c(rep('Young',2),rep('Middle',2),rep('Old',2));Age
Smoker  <- rep(c('Yes','No'),3);Smoker
Died <- c(5,6,92,59,42,165);sum(Died)
Lived <- c(174,213,262,261,7,28);sum(Lived)
smoke <- data.frame(Age,Smoker,Died,Lived);smoke
```

print(xtable(smoke),file='ttt.tex') $ The results are printed in ttt.tex file  
This gives

```
 $\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{rllrr}
      \hline
     & Age & Smoker & Died & Lived \\ 
      \hline
    1 & Young & Yes & 5.00 & 174.00 \\ 
      2 & Young & No & 6.00 & 213.00 \\ 
      3 & Middle & Yes & 92.00 & 262.00 \\ 
      4 & Middle & No & 59.00 & 261.00 \\ 
      5 & Old & Yes & 42.00 & 7.00 \\ 
      6 & Old & No & 165.00 & 28.00 \\ 
       \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}$
```

or 
[image: Output using print and xtable]

Using latex in Hmisc
 
names(smoke) <- NULL
latex(smoke,file='ttt.tex',rowname=NULL)  
We get

```
 $\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llrr}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Age}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Smoker}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Died}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Lived}\tabularnewline
\hline
Young&Yes&$  5$&$174$\tabularnewline
Young&No&$  6$&$213$\tabularnewline
Middle&Yes&$ 92$&$262$\tabularnewline
Middle&No&$ 59$&$261$\tabularnewline
Old&Yes&$ 42$&$  7$\tabularnewline
Old&No&$165$&$ 28$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

or,
[image: Output using latex function Hmisc]

I guess you already know, you need to add `results=tex` in your chunk options field to use latex inside it so that you have a tex output